# How do I compare diferently formatted dates in sql db2?

Tags: sql, db2

One column is formatted like this: dd/mm/yyyy
The other is formatted like this: yyyymmdd
How do I create a select statement which lets me compare these two columns? They are both varchar.
I'm running a db2 database.

Comment: If they are formatted differently, what data type are they? Convert them to DATE data type

Answer (score 0):

I DB2, you can use [`TO_DATE()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007109.html) to convert both string dates to `TIMESTAMP` datatypes (note that `TO_DATE` is a  synonym for the `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` scalar function).

You can then safely compare them:

```
to_date(col1, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = to_date(col2, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.
I used substr:

```
substr(COLUMN_NAME, 7,4) || substr(COLUMN_NAME,4,2) || sub-str(COLUMN_NAME,1,2)
```

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>